# pygtk inline toolbar background

Tags: python, programming, pygtk

as in topic I need your help with inline toolbar for my app.
[image: On the top inline toolbar I want in my app ( on bottom )]

I'll need this background bar to be expanded to the end of the widget while buttons remains on the left, as it is in keyboard layout setting in Ubuntu.

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/259041/pygtk-inline-toolbar-background. You basically need to create a toolbar and set its style to INLINE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok!

Problem was in toolbar widget settings...
After messing up with toolbar setting in glade it is nicely filled in whole container.